# How to gain access to methods of class without inheritance?

Tags: python

I failed to sublcass `pathlib.Path`, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689391/error-with-simple-subclassing-of-pathlib-path-no-flavour-attribute)

Hacky solutions were offered, the linter complains about them. 
What I'm doing at the moment is this:

```
from pathlib import Path
class ExtendedPath:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.orig_path_object = Path(path)
```

So, no inheritance from path. But now in order to access methods of Path I have to refer to the attribute `orig_path_object` which is not convenient.

*My question*: I wonder if there is an elegant way to make methods of `Path` available to `ExtendedPath` without inheritence, specifically, through the `orig_path_object`.

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749914/add-method-to-loaded-class-module-in-python?lq=1 answer your initial question?

Answer (score 0):

Add this method:

```
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.orig_path_object, item)
```

Comment: You should delegate to `getattr`, not `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I tried that, failed. `Path` doesn't have `getattr`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Plus, it worked! so I don't see wht you downvoted it.

Comment: `getattr` is a function, not a method. Objects aren't supposed to have a `getattr` method.

Comment: (Delegating to `__getattribute__` would fail if the pathlib classes ever added a `__getattr__` of their own. The fact that they don't have a `__getattr__` is an implementation detail.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to extend the the `getattr` functionality by checking if the attribute is something belonging to the `orig_path_object` or not. If so, delegate that to `orig_path_object`.

```
from pathlib import Path


class ExtendedPath:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.orig_path_object = Path(path)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.orig_path_object.__dict__:
            return getattr(self.orig_path_object, item)
        else:
            return ... # handle normal case

epath = ExtendedPath(Path('.'))
print(epath.cwd())  # should print the cwd from orig_path_object
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Can you please fill the missing part? how do you handle normal cases and make it revert to methods of `ExtendedPath`?

Comment: You'll need to check `item` & call the specific methods. If you use `getattr` there you'll end up with infinite recursion.

Comment: Are you saying there's going to be some ugly if statements, as many as my methods?

Comment: Or you can get the `item` from `self.__dict__` like `return self.__dict__[item]`

Comment: The `else` for the normal case is not needed because `__getattr__()` is only called for attributes which aren't part of the current class.

Comment: It's not. Also, the `__dict__` check isn't going to find methods.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I just realized that, so I discarded that if statement and went straight `return self.orig_path_object.__getattr__(item)` that should work

Comment: @AlexDeft: Nope. The original path object doesn't have a `__getattr__`, and it would be the wrong thing to delegate to anyway.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I just verified that. Please figure out a solution for me. How come that `Path` has no `getattr` !

Comment: @AlexDeft: `__getattr__` is a completely different thing from `getattr`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Both don't work anyway. I guess we need to tap into the dangerous `getattribute`